# breaking a line at very defined points

Tags: line-breaking

I'm trying to create a macro for generating a title page for manuals. In the simplest case the title should look like

```
{\huge
\textbf{\productname{} \manualtitle{}}
}
```

But I would like to have the following rules applied for line-breaks:

1. If the whole title fits into one line, do not break it.
2. If `manualtitle` fits into one line but not together with `productname`, break between the two.
3. If `manualtitle` is longer than the line, break after `productname` **and** break `manualtitle` automatically but without hyphens.

I know how to get parts of it to work manually using `\newline` and the `hyphenrules` and `sloppypar` environments, but I can't find a solution that fulfills all three requirements.

**Minimal example as requested:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,
            left=25mm,
            right=25mm,
            top=25mm,
            bottom=25mm,
            showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand{\product}{PRODUCT}
\newcommand{\manualtitle}{User Manual}

\newcommand{\printtitle}{
  \vspace{2em}

  {\huge
    \textbf{\product{} \manualtitle{}}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\printtitle

\renewcommand{\manualtitle}{More Important User Manual}
\printtitle

\renewcommand{\manualtitle}{Even Way More Important User Manual}
\printtitle

\end{document}
```

**Desired output:**

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Is the title being typeset in a `center` context?

Comment: Can you make an actual example so that we can test solutions?

Comment: @egreg no, but `flushleft` might be an option

Comment: @samcarter edited the question accordingly

Comment: this tactic is manual, but it's reliable -- use the "tie" `~` form of space to keep words together.  works quite nicely for titles that are defined as ragged right.  (on your last example, i'd use it for "`User~Manual`"..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,
            left=25mm,
            right=25mm,
            top=25mm,
            bottom=25mm,
            showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\newcommand{\product}{PRODUCT}
\newcommand{\manualtitle}{User Manual}

\newcommand{\printtitle}{%
  \par
  \vspace*{2em}%
  \par\begingroup\raggedright
  \huge\bfseries
  \sbox0{\let\\\relax\product{} \manualtitle}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\linewidth
    \product\\
    \manualtitle
    \par
  \else
    \box0
  \fi
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\printtitle

\renewcommand{\manualtitle}{More Important User Manual}
\printtitle

\renewcommand{\manualtitle}{Even Way More Important User Manual}
\printtitle

\renewcommand{\manualtitle}{Even Way More Important \\ User Manual}
\printtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]